Image provider: NetworkImage("null", scale: 1.0) Image key: NetworkImage("null", scale: 1.0)
Please  can you help me or sho me an other logic ,
I tried to show  show slider image from firebase, but when  i run i get   NetworkImage("null", scale: 1.0),
nevertheless, i get  my uid
this my  colection's image

this  my logic
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue[500],
        body: StreamBuilder(
            stream:
                firebaseStore.collection('imagevehicul').doc(uid).snapshots(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> streamSnapshot) {
              if (streamSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return const Text("Loading");
              } else if (streamSnapshot.hasData) {
                return Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      image: DecorationImage(
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          image: NetworkImage(
                              streamSnapshot.data!.data().toString()))),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      uid,
                      style: const TextStyle(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ); // added data()
              } else {
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
            }));
  }


The streamSnapshot.data!.data() will return a list of image url.
///check the data is null or not
final images = List.from(streamSnapshot.data!.data());

return Column(
  children: images
      .map(
        (e) => Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            image: DecorationImage(
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              image: NetworkImage(e),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
      .toList(),


hi,  after tried,  i get this  error ``` The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable'. dartargument_type_not_assignable


Can you try List<String>.from(streamSnapshot.data!.data());
